# Python script to find error code 404 from URL list

Tags: python-3.x

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
import csv
import requests

urllist_404 = []
resplist = []
code_list = []
count = 0

with open('cmsURl.csv1.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

for row in reader:
    urls = row[1]
    request = requests.get(urls)
    request_code = request.status_code
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    if request_code == 404:
       urllist_404.append(urls)
       resplist.append(request.elapsed)
       code_list.append(request_code)
df = DataFrame({'URL': urllist_404, 'Response Code': code_list, 'Response_Time': resplist})
df.to_excel('Error_404_list.xlsx')
```

I am trying to make a python script to find the URLs from a CSV file of over 10000000 URLs that return a response code 404, I need to write the new rows to the output CSV with in the loop so that if the program shuts down because of any reason I could have a saved copy of results until the failure occurred, can anyone suggest how can I make it work

The updated snippet with try-except block, it only runs the script with exit code 0 but doesn't write a new excel file

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import requests

urllist_404 = []
resplist = []
code_list = []
count = 0

with open('BADURLs.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:

        try:
            urls = row[0]
            request = requests.get(urls)
            request_code = request.status_code
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
            if request_code == 404:
                urllist_404.append(urls)
                resplist.append(request.elapsed)
                code_list.append(request_code)
        except:
            break
        df = DataFrame({'URL': urllist_404, 'Response Code': code_list, 'Response_Time': resplist})
        df.to_excel('Error_404_list.xlsx')
```

Comment: pls add try-except block inside the for loop and also in except block "add break keyword" and stop the loop execution, then save a copy of results, this will solve your problem

Comment: have you solved the problem ?

Comment: thanks a lot ..i tried but it will not append the rows bit 9noy overwrite the first row would it be possible for you to update the code??

Comment: can you pls update your snippets above which you tried ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I have updated the snippet , please check and advice me what is wrong here

Comment: Your updated snippets runs fine for me .

Comment: i dont get the output file though..did you get it??

Comment: Yes , i m getting . can you pls share the csv which you tested and also let me know how you run the script ?

Comment: the test data is in the office network but i can create a dummy data file

Comment: i tried with the code as in the screenshot, its going to the except block directly coz the urls are not parsed correctly:

[Pycharm screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/XgeHOhC)

can you tell me whats wrong here, on other PC with same Python 3.1 installation it works

Comment: I think you need to debug this code , in except block please print the error before break statement .

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import requests
import openpyxl

urllist_404 = []
resplist = []
code_list = []
count = 0

with open('urlpages1.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        urls = row[0]
        response = requests.get(urls)
        get_response_code = response.status_code
        if get_response_code == 404:
            urllist_404.append(urls)
            resplist.append(response.elapsed)
            code_list.append(get_response_code)
        df = DataFrame({'URL': urllist_404, 'Response Code': code_list, 'Response_Time': resplist})
df.to_excel('Error_404_list.xlsx')
```

I used a sample csv file with 4urls (3 of google.com and 4th one of google.com/badpage - which gives a 404). I applied the above code on this csv and the new xlsx file would have the last url as it has the 404 response code.

[URL Pages Image New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgWeX.png)

[Error 404 List xlsx Image New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK7Ax.png)

Comment: i think its only going to one row to the excel file not append all the urls with error...means only overwrites the rows

Comment: @mangesh my apology for messing up with the last line indentation. It should be way to the left, aligning with the line indentation of 'with open'. I have edited the code now in the same post. Could you check? This should work with the edit that is done.

Comment: I am running the same code in two PCs , in one it works in one PC but on the other with the same Python version 3.10 and Pycharm or visual studio code I get this error:
[screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/bYRzOdY)
can you help what might be wrong here

Comment: @mangesh did you save the csv file in csv utf-8 format? If so, I am encountering the error you mentioned. Whereas if it is just .csv, i am not encountering any error with the code. I only have one machine to work with so multi-machine test is ruled out for me. As I have seen, it could be due to the csv-utf8 save format. Any other insights anyone?

Comment: i created the csv file using excel 2019, not sure about the unicode..but i will check this anyways..the code works fine though in my other PC